# Spiderfier annotation for Google map

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have many annotation on same coordinate now my map view display a single annotation. Tf I tap the annotation I want to display it like this.[Spiderfier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2FlC.png) Thanks in advance

```
GMSMapView *mapView;
mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
mapView.delegate = self;
self.view = mapView;

for (int i = 0; i < [final_loc count]; i++)
{
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[final_loc objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LAT"]floatValue], [[[final_loc objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LON"]floatValue]);
    marker.title = [[final_loc objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LAT"];
    marker.snippet = [[final_loc objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LON"];
    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Map_pin"];
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker.map = mapView;
}
[_activityindicator stopAnimating];
_overlayView.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: What code have you written?

Comment: Please if you find a lib, I will be so grateful if you will post the link.

Answer (score 1):

@christopher

```
GMSMapView *mapView;
    mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:camera];
    mapView.myLocationEnabled = YES;
    mapView.delegate = self;
    self.view = mapView;

    for (int i = 0; i < [final_loc count]; i++)
    {
        GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake([[[final_loc objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LAT"]floatValue], [[[final_loc objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LON"]floatValue]);
        marker.title = [[final_loc objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LAT"];
        marker.snippet = [[final_loc objectAtIndex:i]valueForKey:@"LON"];
        marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Map_pin"];
        marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
        marker.map = mapView;
    }
    [_activityindicator stopAnimating];
    _overlayView.hidden = YES;
```

Comment: This was my code 
Now all annotations are overlapped here I want to display it as the image posted in the question